# Losing focus on text field

Tags: extjs

Am using extjs 3.0

I have a scenario like

on entering any data on text field and hit enter i have to show a grid based on the value of text field, user keeps on entering the data in text field. but once the grid is created am reloading the store based on the value of text field by setting the value to store as base param.
on the first time of displaying grid focus is loosing from text field,once the grid is visible  the cursor is focusing on the text field.

Am using focus method on text field but its not working...

Help me thanks in advance

Comment: When are you trying to use the [focus()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.TextField-method-focus) method? After the grid has rendered?

Comment: yes,after the grid has rendered i am trying to focus but the focus is changing to child i.e grid. And i am using window to show grid,so am calling window.show(); field.focus();

Comment: Did you try enabling the focusmanager? `Ext.FocusManager.enable()` Edit: Oops that is available since Ext4

Comment: Yes I see, try delaying your focus. `field.focus(500); //500 millisecs`

Comment: yes tried this its working and i also added window.setActive(false);
   field.focus('',1000);
   field.show();                             thank you so much

Comment: I've posted an answer so you can accept it for future reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer the focus with:

```
field.focus(500) //This is 500 milliseconds
```